# Calculate a Confidence measure for Image similarity

Tags: image, image-processing

I am using Euclidean distance between Histograms of 2 images for calculating image similarity.
The Histogram is of 15 bins and is normalized with respect to the image size (Thus, sum of all bins = 1).

Now, for the user, the distance value is not of any use and I want to convert it to a more tangible value - such as a % Confidence measure.
So, if the distance is 0, the confidence is 100% and if the distance is maximum, i.e 1 (is this correct?), then the confidence is 0%.

However, the scaling is not linear because of the properties of the histogram and the distance metric i.e. distance = 0.5 doesn't equal a confidence measure of 50%.

Can someone suggest me a scaling function to convert distance to a confidence measure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give more weight to the results where the distance is closer to 0 with an inverse exponential.  Something to the effect of the following might work, where `d` is the distance:

```
((2 - d) ^ 2 - 1) / 3
```

A distance of 1 would result in a confidence score of 1 (i.e. 100%), and a distance of 1 would result in a confidence of 0.  You'd also get at .5 a confidence of ~0.412.  You can weight the lower distances higher by increasing the exponent and the divisor.  An exponent of 3 instead of 2 would mean you'd want to divide the whole thing by 7 instead of 3, and would pull down a distance of .5 to ~0.339.

Comment: cool! I was trying something like this, but is there a more "rigorous" way to arrive at the formula ?

Comment: Nothing that I know of.  It really just depends on your data and how you want to skew your confidence